# Not able to run automation tests after a setInterval() code implemented in application code

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

We are not able to run our test framework after a setInterval() code has implemented by dev team in our application
Code:

```
this.time = setInterval(() => {
this.gmtTime = new Date();
},1000);
```

Once the framework hits the login page of our application it stays in that page itself not able to do anything beyond that.

Already tried browser.ignoreSyncrhonization = false and true, but it is not working. Tried by upgrading the nodejs and npm version but no luck

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
browser.get(URL);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
var login_page = require('../pages/loginPage');
browser.refresh();
```

Once it hits the page it should login and execute the test cases

Comment: Can you please specify what error do you get

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich In our applicaiton UI, the developers added a running time, it affects the test framework is failing due to this change 
this.time = setInterval(() => {
this.gmtTime = new Date();
},1000);
When we tried to run the test the page behaves weirdly it got shrinked by 50% if we stop the running time without the above time interval. If we had the above code the test itself wont work it stays in the login page itself nothing happens.

Comment: Error : Failed: No active session with ID

Answer (score 0):

browser.driver.sleep(environment.DELAY_TIMEOUT);

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how to install this environment module in my framework it shows  Error: Error: Cannot find module 'environment'. I have used "var environment = require('environment');"

Comment: sorry.. `browser.driver.sleep(1000);` .. just mention the time in milliseconds